# Cannot compile freetype 2.6 in visual studio 2013 - '#include': expected a filename, found 'identifier' error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, compilation, freetype

I am trying to compile freetype 2.6 in visual studio 2013. I've been following the "Install.any" guide included in the freetype download, but when I try to compile I get the errors

> Error 10  error C2006: '#include' : expected a filename, found 'identifier'   d:\projects\car\car\src\thirdparty\common\freetype-2.6\src\base\ftpic.c 21  1   Car
>   Error   11  error C1083: Cannot open include file: '': No such file or directory    d:\projects\car\car\src\thirdparty\common\freetype-2.6\src\base\ftpic.c 21  1   Car
>   Error   12  error C2006: '#include' : expected a filename, found 'identifier'   D:\Projects\Car\Car\src\thirdparty\common\freetype-2.6\src\base\ftbbox.c    28  1   Car
>   Error   13  error C1083: Cannot open include file: '': No such file or directory    D:\Projects\Car\Car\src\thirdparty\common\freetype-2.6\src\base\ftbbox.c    28  1   Car
>   Error   14  error C2006: '#include' : expected a filename, found 'identifier'   D:\Projects\Car\Car\src\thirdparty\common\freetype-2.6\src\base\ftdebug.c   46  1   Car
>   Error   15  error C1083: Cannot open include file: '': No such file or directory    D:\Projects\Car\Car\src\thirdparty\common\freetype-2.6\src\base\ftdebug.c   46  1   Car
>   Error   16  error C2006: '#include' : expected a filename, found 'identifier'   D:\Projects\Car\Car\src\thirdparty\common\freetype-2.6\src\base\ftglyph.c   32  1   Car
>   Error   17  error C1083: Cannot open include file: '': No such file or directory    D:\Projects\Car\Car\src\thirdparty\common\freetype-2.6\src\base\ftglyph.c   32  1   Car
>   Error   18  error C2006: '#include' : expected a filename, found 'identifier'   D:\Projects\Car\Car\src\thirdparty\common\freetype-2.6\src\base\ftinit.c    42  1   Car
>   Error   19  error C1083: Cannot open include file: '': No such file or directory    D:\Projects\Car\Car\src\thirdparty\common\freetype-2.6\src\base\ftinit.c    42  1   Car
>   Error   20  error C2006: '#include' : expected a filename, found 'identifier'   D:\Projects\Car\Car\src\thirdparty\common\freetype-2.6\src\base\ftsystem.c  30  1   Car
>   Error   21  error C1083: Cannot open include file: '': No such file or directory    D:\Projects\Car\Car\src\thirdparty\common\freetype-2.6\src\base\ftsystem.c  30  1   Car

I'm currently only trying to build the bare minimum the guide requires. This seems to be an error that happens when precompiled headers are used, but I have turned them off on my project. I have tried older versions of freetype, but the same problem still occurs.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Update if anyone else has this problem, I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_99R9DZF6c and he was having the same problem. There was a few problems. I just went to his github repository and he had a version there that compiled mostly fine in visual studio after defining a macro FT2_BUILD_LIBRARY.

Answer (score 0):

Do your ftbbox.c file has this line?

```
#include <ft2build.h>
```

This includes 'ftheader.h', which contains macro definitions for path to other header files. For example,

```
#define FT_BBOX_H  <ftbbox.h>
```

When you go to ftbbox.c, you will be able to find this line:

```
#include FT_BBOX_H
```

which feeds string literal defined as macro constant.

Now what will happen if you don't define FT_BBOX_H?
compiler will see FT_BBOX_H as a identifier(variable name), and complain that you cannot feed identifier to #include preprocessor.

So it is either your project doesn't know necessary [additional include directory](https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=additional%20include%20directories%20visual%20studio&oq=additional%20include%20directories%20visual%20studio&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.10646j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8), or your files don't include 'ft2build.h' on top. That is all that I can imagine from what is given in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click Project -> *Properties* -> *VC++ Directories* and add wherever you put freetype\include to *Include Directories*.  Then `#include <ft2build.h>`.